# Select the next list group and change data-state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, iteration

When a list-group being clicked, I need to select the next (following) list group to the and change it to data-state=enabled .list-group and remove the class `disabled` from each list-group-item

https://jsbin.com/zakuro

My code is getting convoluted and I would like to know 
1) How to get the counter working so it doesn't throw errors by incrementing too much
2) How to simplify this without using jquery
3) How to simplify this using jquery

```
            <section>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <h4>1. Select Doctor</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Dr. Justice Freedom</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Martin Fabio</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Jenny Walter</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Loius Von Winkle</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Mary McDoctors</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Freethinker Liver</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dr. Cognitive Thinker</a>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div class="list-group" data-state="disabled">
                    <h4>2. Select Department</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Cras justo odio</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled active">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Morbi leo risus</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Vestibulum at eros</a>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div class="list-group" data-state="disabled">
                    <h4>3. Select Area</h4>
                    <hr>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled active">Cras justo odio</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Morbi leo risus</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item disabled">Vestibulum at eros</a>
                </div>
            </section>
```

JS

```
var listGroup = document.querySelectorAll('#selectPatientCategories .list-group');
//console.log(listGroup);

var cats = document.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');
//console.log(cats);
var counter = 1;
// For each category list item
var catIndex = 0, catLength = cats.length;
for (; catIndex < catLength; catIndex++) {

 var thiscat = cats[catIndex];
//console.log(listGroupIndex);

// Click function on list item
thiscat.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //console.log(thisListGroup);

    //Get the parent .list-group
    thisListGroup = this.parentElement;
    thisListGroupCats = thisListGroup.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');

    //console.log(thisListGroupCats);

    // For each category .list-group-item within this listGroup
    var listGroupIndex = 0, listGroupCatsLength = thisListGroupCats.length;
    for (; listGroupIndex < listGroupCatsLength; listGroupIndex++) {

        // Focus on just this .list-group being iterated
        rmThisCat = thisListGroupCats[listGroupIndex];
        rmThisCat.classList.remove('active');

    }
    // Activate the clicked .list-group-item
    this.classList.add('active');

    // Activate the next list group
    nextListGroup = listGroup[counter];
    nextListGroup.setAttribute('data-state', 'enabled');

    nextListGroupCats = nextListGroup.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');
    nextCatIndex = 0;
    console.log(nextListGroupCats);
    for (; nextCatIndex < nextListGroupCats.length; nextCatIndex++) {
        var nextCat = nextListGroupCats[nextCatIndex];
        nextCat.classList.remove('disabled');
    }
    // increment the counter
    counter++;
}); // End click function
}
```

Comment: Your requirement 2) How to simplify this without using jquery 3) How to simplify this using jquery contradicts. Would you be willing to adapt a jquery version ?

Comment: Sure, the reason I asked about both was in case someone answered in javascript, I could figure out a jquery version, and visa versa, so I can learn better. Jquery version is fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution. Again , this is the jquery implementation. You might convert the logic to plain js as per your needs.

```
$(document).on("click",".list-group a[class='list-group-item']",function()
{
    alert();
    var listGroup = $(this).parent();
    if (listGroup.attr("data-state") !== "disabled") 
    {
        $(listGroup).find("a").removeClass("active");    
        $(this).addClass("active");

        var nextListGroup =
            listGroup.parent().next().find("div");
         $(nextListGroup).attr("data-state","");
         $(nextListGroup).find("a").removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j2c59j9j/6/

With different selector approach :

```
$(".list-group a[class^='list-group-item']").click(function()
{
    var listGroup = $(this).parent();
    if (listGroup.attr("data-state") !== "disabled") 
 {
$(listGroup).find("a").removeClass("active");    
$(this).addClass("active");

var nextListGroup =
    listGroup.parent().next().find("div");
 $(nextListGroup).attr("data-state","");
 $(nextListGroup).find("a").removeClass("disabled");
 }

});
```

Comment: Awesome. That works great. The only thing to add to this would be: Disable clicks from being registered on the disabled list-groups, until they become enabled. Because right now I can click the second or third list-group and it activates, when it should remain with no change on click.

Comment: you could easily shortcircuit the handler by checking if $(this).hasClass("disabled")

Comment: The code in your first block only works on clicking the first list-group to activate the second, but clicking the second does not activate the third.  On the second code block you provided, the same occurs. But the code inside your jsfiddle version 6 works as expected, and is different from both of these provided here. If you update your provided code with the jsfiddle version I can accept your answer.

Comment: Although I am a bit confused on how the jsfiddle version 6 is accomplishing this since I don't see any hasClass("disabled") in it.

Comment: In reality you don't need hasClass("disabled"). Once you apply class="disabled", the element is not intractable and would never trigger the click event on 'a' tags. I'm not sure how you have implemented it at your end, so i added that condition just in case.

Comment: I fixed it. I had to change ` if(!listGroup.hasClass("disabled"))`  to  `if (listGroup.attr("data-state") !== "disabled") ` because it is using data-state not classes (my original html had a mistake in it where it showed both classes and data-states)

Answer (score 0):

I created the pure javascript version based on DinoMyte's answer:

https://jsbin.com/weteseq

```
//Vanilla JS version of apply class "active" on click of .list-group-item

var listGroup = document.querySelectorAll('#selectPatientCategories .list-group');
//console.log(listGroup);

var cats = document.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');
//console.log(cats);

// For each category list item
var catIndex = 0, catLength = cats.length;
for (; catIndex < catLength; catIndex++) {
    var thiscat = cats[catIndex];
    //console.log(listGroupIndex);

    // Click function on list item
    thiscat.addEventListener('click', function () {
        //console.log(thisListGroup);

        //Get the parent .list-group
        thisListGroup = this.parentElement;
        thisListGroupCats = thisListGroup.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');

        if (thisListGroup.getAttribute("data-state") === "disabled") {
            return false;
        } else {
            //console.log(thisListGroupCats);

            // For each category .list-group-item within this listGroup
            var listGroupIndex = 0, listGroupCatsLength = thisListGroupCats.length;
            for (; listGroupIndex < listGroupCatsLength; listGroupIndex++) {

                // Focus on just this .list-group being iterated
                rmThisCat = thisListGroupCats[listGroupIndex];
                rmThisCat.classList.remove('active');

            }
            // Activate the clicked .list-group-item
            this.classList.add('active');
            //console.log(thisListGroup);

            // Activate the next list group
            nextListGroup = thisListGroup.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
            if (nextListGroup) { //if its not NULL
                nextListGroupQuery = nextListGroup.querySelector('.list-group');
                //console.log(nextListGroup);
                nextListGroupQuery.setAttribute('data-state', 'enabled');

                nextListGroupCats = nextListGroupQuery.querySelectorAll('a.list-group-item');
                nextCatIndex = 0;
                //console.log(nextListGroupCats);
                for (; nextCatIndex < nextListGroupCats.length; nextCatIndex++) {
                    var nextCat = nextListGroupCats[nextCatIndex];
                    nextCat.classList.remove('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    }); // End click function
}
```